# Flutter build APK results in "resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found"

Tags: android-studio, flutter, build, apk, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to create a signed APK in Flutter with Android Studio, in theory I already have all the steps ready to create the signed APK "https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android" but an error always pops up that prevents the apk from being created.

```
C:\Users\CryptoBrain\Desktop\app-Flutter\my_app>flutter build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':clipboard_manager:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > 1 exception was raised by workers:
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed

     C:\Users\CryptoBrain\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6c261a14fef7a6c9650e745991e1078b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVar
iationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\CryptoBrain\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6c261a14fef7a6c9650e745991e1078b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcInde
x not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 10m 59s

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          665,6s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin clipboard_manager...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                        59,7s
√ Built build\app\outputs\repo.
Building plugin majascan...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                        36,6s
√ Built build\app\outputs\repo.
Building plugin shared_preferences...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                         1,4s

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

The plugin shared_preferences could not be built due to the issue above.

C:\Users\CryptoBrain\Desktop\app-Flutter\my_app>
```

I already tried using the different versions of clipboard_manager there are 4 but they all give the same error.

Also change the com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 and the distributionUrl I have it in: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

Here is the code I am using:

pubspec.yaml

```
name: app_name
description: my flutter app

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  flutter_screenutil: ^0.5.3
  carousel_pro: ^0.0.13
  flutter_sparkline: ^0.1.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.4.0
  shimmer: ^0.0.6
  rxdart: ^0.21.0
  bmnav: ^0.3.4
  carousel_slider: ^1.3.0
  percent_indicator: ^1.0.15
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.1+1
  http: 0.12.0+4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  pin_code_fields: ^3.0.0
  url_launcher: ^5.4.5
  provider: ^4.0.1
  clipboard_manager: ^0.0.4
  aes_crypt: ^0.1.1
  mvc_pattern: ^5.1.1
  encrypt: any
  majascan: ^0.3.7
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/image/logo.png"
  ios: true
  android: true
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true


  fonts:
    - family: gainers
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/icon/ic_gainers.ttf
    - family: message
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/icon/ic_message.ttf
    - family: tab
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/icon/ic_tab.ttf
    - family: wallet
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/icon/ic_wallet.ttf
    - family: tab1
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/icon/ic_tab1.ttf
    - family: tab2
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/icon/ic_tab2.ttf
    - family: tab3
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/icon/ic_tab3.ttf
    - family: tab4
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/icon/ic_tab4.ttf
    - family: tab5
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/icon/ic_tab5.ttf
    - family: loser
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/icon/ic_loser.ttf
    - family: Sans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/font/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 800
        - asset: assets/font/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/font/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/font/OpenSans-Light.ttf
          weight: 200
    - family : Popins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/font/Poppins-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/font/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
          weight : 600
    - family : Berlin
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/font/BRLNSDB.TTF
          weight: 700
    - family : Lemon
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/font/Lemon-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
    - family : Gotik
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/font/GOTHIC.TTF
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/font/GOTHICB.TTF
          weight : 600
    - family : Pragmatica
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/font/pragmatica_bold.ttf
          weight: 500

  assets:
    - assets/font/BRLNSDB.TTF
    - assets/font/GOTHIC.TTF
    - assets/font/GOTHICB.TTF
    - assets/font/Lemon-Regular.ttf
    - assets/font/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
    - assets/font/OpenSans-Light.ttf
    - assets/font/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
    - assets/font/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf
    - assets/font/Poppins-Regular.ttf
    - assets/font/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
    - assets/font/pragmatica-bold.ttf
    - assets/font/pragmatica.ttf
    - assets/font/pragmatica_bold.ttf
    - assets/icon/ic_gainers.ttf
    - assets/icon/ic_loser.ttf
    - assets/icon/ic_message.ttf
    - assets/icon/ic_tab.ttf
    - assets/icon/ic_tab1.ttf
    - assets/icon/ic_tab2.ttf
    - assets/icon/ic_tab3.ttf
    - assets/icon/ic_tab4.ttf
    - assets/icon/ic_tab5.ttf
    - assets/icon/ic_wallet.ttf
    - assets/image/
    - assets/image/market/
    - assets/image/logo.png
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

file app/build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.flutter.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

File android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the android/app/build.gradle under configuration, to resolve the issue

```
  android{
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello, could you tell me in which line number I should add the code?
I tried to add the code to the beginning and the end of the file but it doesn't work at all, I keep getting the same error...

Comment: Hi @CrDiego I have modified the code snippet .. please refer to it

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting that kind of error but instead, I KNOW ANOTHER WAY.

**Step 01**: Open your flutter Android app in another android studio. If you don't know how? Just open `build.gradle` in the android section of the flutter app. Then at the top corner, you will find **Open for Editing in Android Studio**.

[image]

**Step 02**: Once a new Window of Android Studio opens. Let the Gradle Build complete. Once it's done go to the Build tab at the top of Android Studio

[image]

**Step 03**: It will open a dialog box and you will figure out what to do next. It's really convenient and easy way.

[image]

Comment: Please don't use quote `>` formatting unless your material is a quote. A quote is something said by someone/something else (a person, a book, a manual, a speech, a website, etc).

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, it is true and apparently it works very well in android studio but I would like very much to be able to solve and create the APK from Flutter since I have some doubts when creating the APP for iOS in case I have the same error , I know it's from a mac but I don't have one, so I still can't see if I'll have problems with flutter at the time of building the app.